# How can i make this conditional return a value IF the output is a number?

Tags: if-statement, vim, conditional-statements, statusline

i am making this function for my vim-statusline:

```
function! GitCommitSymbol(timer_id)
  let l:uncommited = system('echo -n $(git checkout | grep -oP "(\M+)" -c)')
  if (uncommited == number)
    let g:uncommited = ''
    hi MyGitSymbol ctermfg=11
  else
    let g:uncommited = ''
    hi MyGitSymbol ctermfg=7
  endif
  call timer_start(30000, 'GitCommitSymbol')
endfunction
```

And i made this command `git checkout | grep -oP "(\M+)" -c` specifically to return only a number of uncommited changes (that's why i use grep).

So basically, if im on a location that is a git repository and i type the command on the shell, it returns me "0", "1" and so on, depending on how much uncommited changes i have.

However, if i type it on a location that is not a git repository, it returns me something like:

`fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /) Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set). 0`

So, on this line of the function: `if (uncommited == number)`, i need a conditional, to show something IF the output of the command is numeric, and the "else" is for when it is not numeric (like the "fatal" output i put above). But i don't know how to make this conditional.

Comment: See `:help v:shell_error`. But there is a cleaner alternative: check if you are in a Git repository before calling Git. See `:help finddir()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the extra `echo`, just call the command directly, then use Vimscript's `trim()` to remove whitespace around the output.

```
let uncommitted = trim(system('git checkout | grep -oP "(\M+)" -c'))
```

Then you can check if it's a number by using the `=~` operator, together with a regex such as `'^\d\+$'` to match numeric output:

```
if uncommitted =~ '^\d\+$'
```

If later on you would like to access the count as a number, you can use `str2nr(uncommitted)`.